# Не убирается строка оповещения php

Tags: php

```
if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-]+@([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,6}$/", $_POST['to'])) {
echo 'не правильный email';

}
```

Если вводится неправильный эмеил, то соответственно выводится строка, которая это оповещает. Как ее потом убрать, ведь после обычного обновления F5 она на месте?

Answer (score 1):

```
if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-]+@([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,6}$/", $_POST['to'])) {
echo 'не правильный email';
unset($_POST['to']);

}
```

Comment: никакого результата((

Answer (score 0):

По нажатию на клафишу F5 после отправки формы у вас POST данные снова отправляются. Поэтому необходимо делать защиту от повторной отправки формы. Как правило это делается на сессиях.

Comment: да они отправляются снова только если правильный эмеил, а как в сессиях это сдлеать что бы не отправлялись?

Comment: по F5 данные отправляются в обработчик независимо от того правильный он или нет. И это неважно, вам нужно защититься от повотрной отправки формы. Если, к примеру, форма отправляет какой-нибудь заказ. Нажимается кнопка отправить, форма ушла, заказ сворировался. Нажимаем F5 еще 10 раз... итого у вас в базе 11 одинаковых заказов. Погуглите на тему "защита от повторной отправки формы", наверняка найдете в первых местах выдачи то, что нужно.

Answer (score 0):

Обычно делают проверку по get параметру. Например, так:

```
if(isset($_GET['act']) && $_GET['act']=='send_email')
if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-]+@([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,6}$/", $_POST['to'])) {
echo 'не правильный email';
}
```

И в форме, в которой пользователь вводит этот email, нужно указать `... </form>`

Да, после обновления F5 ошибка останется. Зато если перейти по этому, адресу исчезнет. А когда нажимаете f5F5, браузер должен запрашивать разрешение повторно отправить post параметры.

ps: если страницы отличаются то нужно явно указывать страницу `action="index.php?act=send_email"> ...`

Comment: форма есть, header("LOCATION: index.php"); исправило повторения отправки письма после нажатия F5, но почему то всегда висит надпись не правильный email, а должна выводится если не корректно выводят эмеил и пропадать после обновления страницы